# Закрыть\Открыть окно на ховер

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой пример, нужно при наведении открывать модалку, когда мышка убираем с ссылки, окно закрывается. Как такое реализовать ?

```js
$('.open-popup-link').mouseover(function() {
  $.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
      src: '.white-popup' // can be a HTML string, jQuery object, or CSS selector
    }
  })
});
$.magnificPopup.close();
```

```css
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css">


<a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link">Show inline popup</a>

<!-- Popup itself -->
<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  Popup content
</div>
```

Comment: А попап должен прикрывать линк или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем виде проблема состоит в том, что при открытии модального окна связь курсора со ссылкой разрывается (появляется прокладка в виде этого самого popup). Поэтому ховер срабатывает только на открытие.

Чтобы он срабатывал и в обратную сторону, ссылке надо задать position: relative и z-index

```js
$('a').hover(function(){ 
    $('.fon, .popup').css('display','block')
  },
  function(){
    $('.fon, .popup').css('display','none')
});
```

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .6;
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<a href="">Наведи на меня свой курсор</a>

<div class="fon"></div>
<div class="popup">Какой-то текст</div>
```